# Installing Joomla using WebMatrix - HTTP Error 500

Tags: joomla, webmatrix

I'm installing Joomla using WebMatrix and I get HTTP Error 500.0 (Microsoft Knowledge Base Article:" 294807) when I try to run it. I did it on two computers and virtual machine and I still get the error. Although my friend installed it without problems. Could you please help me with this issue?

Comment: Did you see any errors occur while you installed it? Is IIS Express (the local web development server) running? You can try to click Stop/Start in the WebMatrix interface to try to reset the server instance.

Comment: It has been solved. It appeared that the problem was caused by the password to Joomla admin site provided during the installation. It seems that it should have NO special characters like $^&* etc.

Answer (score 1):

Problem can easely be solved: Run 'Web Platform Installer' again and add '**URL Rewrite 2.0**' .
This did the trick for me .